# -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] was unable to load a nib

Tags: iphone, sdk, crash, nib

I have purchased an Apple IOS certificate and now i'm building my first app onto a real device. But i got a problem. One of my views is a gallery that has no nib file and in simulator is working perfectly. When i "build and go" on a device and go to the gallery view i get this error into the console and the app crashes

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] was unable to load a nib named "iCarouselExampleViewController"'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x35f08c7b __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x30186ee8 objc_exception_throw + 40
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x35f08ac3 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 70
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x35f08af7 +[NSException raise:format:] + 30
    4   UIKit                               0x339c64a0 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 300
    5   UIKit                               0x339c5280 -[UIViewController loadView] + 128
    6   UIKit                               0x3386edf4 -[UIViewController view] + 52
    7   UIKit                               0x3387ff34 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 32
    8   UIKit                               0x3387fd54 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 44
    9   UIKit                               0x3387fc00 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 36
    10  UIKit                               0x3387f52c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 520
    11  UIKit                               0x3387f290 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 264
    12  UIKit                               0x3386ec4c -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 912
    13  UIKit                               0x3386e8b0 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 44
    14  BlazingStump                        0x00002663 -[RootViewController galleryView] + 94
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x35eada43 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 26
    16  UIKit                               0x3384af20 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 136
    17  UIKit                               0x3384ae88 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 40
    18  UIKit                               0x3384ae50 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 52
    19  UIKit                               0x3384aaa0 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 536
    20  UIKit                               0x3384b5cc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 460
    21  UIKit                               0x3383ceb0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 588
    22  UIKit                               0x3383c4e4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 396
    23  UIKit                               0x3381fc9c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 452
    24  UIKit                               0x3381f3b4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6824
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x35262c88 PurpleEventCallback + 1048
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x35e9a5cb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x35e9a589 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 164
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x35e8c835 __CFRunLoopRun + 580
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x35e8c50b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 226
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x35e8c419 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 60
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x35261d24 GSEventRunModal + 196
    32  UIKit                               0x3386557c -[UIApplication _run] + 588
    33  UIKit                               0x33862558 UIApplicationMain + 972
    34  BlazingStump                        0x000023dd main + 48
    35  BlazingStump                        0x000023a8 start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
(gdb)
```

is it something with teh navigation controller? because my app is navigation based application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call initWithNibName and not give it a nib.  You can just call init.  That should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the navigation controller its clearly looking for a nib called iCarouselExampleViewController.

Answer (score 0):

iCarouselExampleViewController is wat code is looking for crackity_jones is right

Comment: OK but why? Here is how i go to it  `-(IBAction)galleryView{ 
 galleryViewController = [[iCarouselExampleViewController alloc] 
        initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 
 galleryViewController.title = @"Gallery";
 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:galleryViewController animated:YES];
 [galleryViewController release]; 
 
}`